# how to design an IDE for GCC using Java?

Tags: gcc

I have already created a text editor using Netbeans in Java and I want to know to link the text editor with the GCC compiler in Linux Platform.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Runtime 'exec' method to execute the program you want (gcc) with the parameters you want (the file names to compile). From there you get a process object that you can use to read the output streams from the executed program.